# How to gross select vertices

Tags: materials, edit-mode, vertices, color

I'm trying to model a strawberry. I want to assign the color orange to the achenes of the fruit, but I can't start selecting the vertices one after the other as it could be time-consuming. Is there any trick to how I can select them all?

[image]

Comment: You had no luck with selection functions from the "select similar" command like face sets, amount of connecting edges...?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "achene", but try selecting one group of vertices and then use the Select > Select all by Trait > Faces by Sides menu.

Comment: @Carlo I'm returning to using Blender, so I can't quite remember most functions anymore. How do I go about the "select similar" command?

Comment: @JohnEason Like the pimples on the body; the pointy pointy extruding circles. Alright I'll try it.

Comment: You can follow the answer below to acces the "select similar menu". I think you should be able to find a selection pattern that suits your case.

Answer (score 4):

1. Select one of the areas that you want to change.
2. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and choose *Area*.

That selects all faces with a similar area as the active one. In the lower left part of the viewport, you'll see options for the selection method, where you can adjust the threshold.

Comment: In this topo,  vertex > number of  connecting edges might be good, too